# shap.summary_plot does not recognise 'T0'

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I am trying to generate a SHAP summary plot to interpret variable importance in a causal forest assessessment of heterogeneous treatment effects from an RCT, but encountering a persistent Key Error.

When I run the code below:

```
import shap
from econml.dml import CausalForestDML


# fit causal forest with default parameters 
causal_forest = CausalForestDML()
causal_forest.fit(Y, T, X=X, W=W)

# calculate shap values of causal forest model 
shap_values = causal_forest.shap_values(X)
# plot shap values 
shap.summary_plot(shap_values['Y0']['T0'])
```

I get the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-8-81b4f1963505>", line 12, in <module>
    shap.summary_plot(shap_values['Y0']['T0'])

KeyError: 'T0'
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong? It appears that 'T0' does not appear in the object 'shap_values'. Any help appreciated.

Code taken from the extremely helpful blog:
https://towardsdatascience.com/causal-machine-learning-for-econometrics-causal-forests-5ab3aec825a7

My shap_values dictionary looks like this. Is it possible that this has generated incorrectly?

[shap_values dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDmSU.png)

Comment: print the columns of shap_values and you will see your error.

Comment: Could it be that you're using a different data set than the tutorial and thus may have different column names?

Comment: Thank you both for the prompt responses. I have added a screenshot of my shap_values dictionary above. Does this look correct to you? My sense is that it may not have generated properly. RefinancedYN is the outcome variable.

Comment: @ShaneByrne were you able to resolve the issue? I have the same problem...